# Can I monitor data of variables while simulating Arduino on Proteus?

Tags: simulator

I simulate Arduino UNO on proteus 8 Pro. I use Arduino software for writing a program.

Is it possible to trace or know the data that are stored in valuables while running the code on Proteus?

I would like to know how the code is running step by step so that I can find logical errors.

Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. By using several tools on "Virtual Instruments Mode" such as SPI-Debugger, I2C-Debugger, Virtual Terminal, or Logic Analyser.

> I would like to know how the code is running step by step so that I can find logical errors.

For example, you can use Virtual Terminal and print the value of variables you want to examine
[image]